# Hide Li class child elements upon jquery click function

Tags: jquery, class, html-lists, dropdown

I am trying hide the
`ul class="sub_menu"` once li a.first class has been clicked. I am able to hide the ul class="sub_menu" with the following code

`$("ul.sub_menu").css('display', 'none');`

Hover the border doesnt callapse back to the starting point of the dropdowntop to only show 'SORT BY'

```js
var maxHeight = 400;

$(function() {
  $(".dopdown > li").hover(function() {
    var $container = $(this),
      $list = $container.find("ul"),
      $anchor = $container.find("a"),
      height = $list.height() * 1.1, // make sure there is enough room at the bottom
      multiplier = height / maxHeight; // needs to move faster if list is taller

    // need to save height here so it can revert on mouseout            
    $container.data("origHeight", $container.height());

    // so it can retain it's rollover color all the while the dropdown is open
    $anchor.addClass("hover");
    // make sure dropdown appears directly below parent list item    
    $list
      .show()
      .css({
        paddingTop: $container.data("origHeight")
      });

    // don't do any animation if list shorter than max
    if (multiplier > 1) {
      $container
        .css({
          height: maxHeight,
          overflow: "hidden"
        })
        .mousemove(function(e) {
          var offset = $container.offset();
          var relativeY = ((e.pageY - offset.top) * multiplier) - ($container.data("origHeight") * multiplier);
          if (relativeY > $container.data("origHeight")) {
            $list.css("top", -relativeY + $container.data("origHeight"));
          };
        });
    }
  }, function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    // put things back to normal
    $el
      .height($(this).data("origHeight"))
      .find("ul")
      .css({
        top: 0
      })
      .hide()
      .end()
      .find("a")
      .removeClass("hover");
  });
});

$("li a.first").click(function() {
  $("#showme").css('display', 'block');
  $("ul.sub_menu").css('display', 'none');
});
```

```css
ul.dopdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  width: 170px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
}

ul.dopdown li {
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

ul.dopdown a:hover {
  color: #000;
}

ul.dopdown li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 7px;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2000;
  font: 500 10px lucida grande, sans-serif;
}

ul.dopdown li a.hover {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  position: relative;
}


/* 
    LEVEL TWO
*/

ul.dopdown ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 170px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

ul.dopdown ul li {
  font-weight: normal;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
  list-style: none
}

ul.dopdown ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  background: #fff !important;
  font: 500 11px lucida grande, sans-serif;
}

ul.dopdown ul li a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  background: #fff !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a.dopdown-toggle:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#showme {
  margin-left: 220px;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dopdown">
  <!-- dopdown one - move right -->
  <li><a class="dopdown-toggle">SORT BY</a>
    <ul class="sub_menu">
      <li><a class="first">Artificial Turf</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Benches</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Netting</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Outdoor Furniture &amp; Storage</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Outdoor Signs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Padding</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Netting</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Outdoor Furniture &amp; Storage</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Outdoor Signs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Padding</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Artificial Turf</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Benches &amp; Bleachers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Communication Devices</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dugouts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fencing &amp; Windscreen</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Floor Protectors</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Foul Poles</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Netting</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Outdoor Furniture &amp; Storage</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Outdoor Signs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Padding</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Scoreboards</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shade Structures</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>

<div id="showme"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity... How  is this *"dropdown"* supposed to work on mobile? And what about users with disabilities? How are they supposed to pinpoint and click a link while they move the mouse with shaky hands? Or people who don't use the mouse at all? This is such a bad (terrible) UI/UX.

Comment: I suggest you go back to the drawing board. Delete the entire JS, use only CSS. Create a dropdown that can opened using :hover and tab key on :focus, and can be scrolled using the mousewheel, and all the sub-list items accessed using the tabs as well.

Comment: I don't understand the question. When the menu collapses, the border shrinks to just the `SORT BY`.

Comment: point taken. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @Barmar only when hovered out of dropdown but not after click. I would like to know the solution but have taken on board Roko comments.